# Use of shift statement in the script

Tags: linux, bash

I was going through a bash script and wanted to understand below piece, mainly the `shift` statement...what actually it's doing?

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        --mirror)
            mirror="$2"
            shift
            ;;
        --dry-run)
            DRY_RUN=1
            ;;
        --*)
            echo "Illegal option $1"
            ;;
    esac
    shift $(( $# > 0 ? 1 : 0 ))
done
```

Comment: Basically, it discards $1 (because you finished with it), and renumbers all the other arguments from 2->1, 3->2 ... all the way up. Very standard shell idiom.

Comment: Not good code anyway. It uses $2 for mirror even if it is undefined. A better style is to check ${#} for args that take parameters, and shift correctly in every case, not have a dangly bit at the end. It also carries on after an invalid option, and has no (*) default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to the script come in the positional parameters, `$1`, `$2`, ... `shift` drops the first one, and moves the rest to the left. So if the arguments are `foo`, `bar`, `doo`, after a shift they'll be `bar`, `doo`. An argument to shift tells how many steps shift, `shift` without an argument is the same as `shift 1`.

The usual form of a loop like this is something like this:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do 
    # work with $1...
    shift
done
```

The loop goes on as long as there are arguments, `$#` contains their number. Each iteration of the loop looks at the first argument, and the final shift removes it and moves to the next one.

In your code, the final shift takes a conditional argument, `$(( $# > 0 ? 1 : 0 ))` is `1` as long as `$#` is greater than 0, i.e. if there are any arguments left; and `0` if there aren't. Usually, that would resolve to just `1`, since, well, we just checked the same thing before going to the loop.

But if the script got `--mirror` as the final argument, the shift in the branch for `--mirror` would remove it, and there'd be none left. A subsequent `shift 1` would return with a failure. The condition here avoids that. Not that the error would matter, unless the script runs with `set -e`, which would check each and every command for failure.